Will DMZ mode do the equivalent of All-Port forwarding
I have an ISP supplied modem that I have to use, because others tell me that Telstra will not give me the access details if I want to use my own modem.
For now, what I have done is to forward a large chunk of the ports from (80 to 65535) from the ISP supplied modem to my Unify Dream Machine Pro.  This seems to be working fine.  For instance, the 300+ attacks per day on my NAS box are now blocked by the UDM.
From reading about the DMZ mode, it seems to me that perhaps I can set up the ISP supplied modem to use DMZ instead of the port forwarding..
Is the DMZ meant for this purpose?

So you are forwarding all ports to a device that is acting like a firewall or intrusion detection system; what exactly is the problem?  Any attacks would be prevented.

Friends are telling me I should use DMZ mode, which I have never used before.  If this does the equivalent of port forwarding, maybe it is faster, perhaps it has other benefits.

Yes, it will. You'll be running a double NAT, with everything not explicitly forwarded at the modem going to the Unifi device. Some people (correctly?) consider a double NAT to be an inelegant way to do things - but if bridge mode isn't an option, its the way to keep control of your network on a machine you own. I generally get good (close to gigabit line speed) on either subnet, so I don't think there would be a significant different in performance.
